# Find Number of Iterations of Euler's Method in order to approximate $\pi$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, pi

I am given the function $x(t)=4 \arctan t$ and told that routine computations will show that $x(0)=0$ and $x(1)=\pi$.

I must determine a differential equation for $x(t)$ of the form $x'(t)=f(t,x)$.

I must then use $f$ to approximate $\pi$.

I will use Euler's Method to find minimum number of iterations ($n$) needed to yield the approximation $\pi ≈ 3.1400$, such that $n−1$ iterations is strictly less than $3.1400$.

How do I find $n$? It seems to me that it can't be found given the instruction set that I am provided.

Comment: You are trying to find $f$? Can't you just differentiate $x$?

Comment: Yes, $x'(t) = 4/(1 + t^2) = f(x,t)$

Comment: I don't know estimate the error of Euler's method so precisely, other than multiple numerical calculations. I suggest you rewrite your post to make it about what you really need to find.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are expected to divide $[0,1]$ into $n$ intervals, use Euler's method to integrate $\frac 1{1+t^2}$ over the interval and see what you get for $x=1$.  For $n=5$, you would compute $x(\frac 15)=x(0)+\frac 15 x'(0)=0+\frac 15 \cdot 1=0.2$, $x(\frac 25)=x(\frac 15)+\frac 15x'(\frac 15)\approx 0.2+\frac 15 \cdot 0.961538\approx0.392308,$ continue stepping until you get to $x(1)$, and compare it with $\frac \pi 4$.  The problem I have is that the derivative is decreasing over the interval, so the forward Euler's method overestimates the function, while the problem assumes it underestimates the function.  At $n=10$ I get $x(1)\approx 0.809981$, an error of about $0.025.$  Since the global truncation error goes as $\frac 1n$, we would expect to need $10$ times more terms to get the error to be below $0.0025$ so the error in $\pi$ is less than $0.01$ and that is what I find in Excel. You would need to look more closely to find the exact $n$ required.

Comment: One can use Taylor's theorem in the Lagrange form to show that the error $E_n$ at the $n$th time step in Euler's method (with uniform step size) satisfies $E_{n+1} = (1+h f_x(t_n,\eta_n)) E_n - \frac{h^2}{2} x''(\tau_n)$, where $x$ is the actual solution and $\eta_n,\tau_n$ are unknown times between $t_n$ and $t_{n+1}$. Here $f_x$ is just zero, so the final error is just a sum of $h^2/2 x''(\tau_n)$. It is not hard to see (in this unusually nice case) that $|x''| \leq 1$. Hence $|E|$ is at most $\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{h^2}{2}=h/2$ where $N=1/h$. (Here I am approximating $\pi/4$, not $\pi$.)

Comment: (Cont.) So getting an error of at most $0.001$ in approximating $\pi$ would need $4 \cdot (h/2)<0.001$ or $h<0.0005$. I agree with Ross Millikan here that Euler's method should give an overestimate in this circumstance.

Comment: @Ian:  I was taking the allowable error in $\pi$ to be $0.01$ as the original question talked about $\pi \approx 3.14$, leading to $h=0.01$ working. I didn't check that something smaller wouldn't.  The question seems to want the smallest $n=\frac 1h$ that will work, but I left that as an exercise.